# how to save image with an android and vb.net

Tags: android, vb.net-2010

I have a program to add images in the language vb.net in the database mysql I want to display the picture in the android and save it in the database sqlite but not working

the code 
vb.net

```
       If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim path As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(path)

        Using picture As Image = Image.FromFile(path)


            Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream
                picture.Save(stream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
                Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO table_news (Title, 
                Image) VALUES (@Id, @Id1)", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Id", TextBox1.Text))
                cmd.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@Id1", ImByte))
                If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                conn.Close()
```

and code android

```
public ArrayList<row> list = new ArrayList<row>();
public ArrayList<row> get_all_new () {

    try {
        String sql =
                "SELECT * FROM table_news ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
        statement = (Statement) connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = (JDBC4ResultSet) statement.executeQuery(sql);
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            row b = new row(
                resultSet.getString("Title"),
                resultSet.getBytes("Image"),
                resultSet.getString("Table"),
                resultSet.getString("Details _tab"),
                resultSet.getString("Count")
                        );
        list.add(b);
                            }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.d("msg",ex.getMessage().toString());
    }
return list;
 }


class row{
String Title;
byte [] Image;
String table1;
String Details;
String Count1;
public row (String Title,byte [] Image,String table1,String Details,String 
 Count1){
    this.Title = Title;
    this.Image = Image;
    this.table1 = table1;
    this.Details = Details;
    this.Count1 = Count1;

     }
```

and save in sqlite code

```
   public void Insert_news(String titel, byte [] Image, String table, String 
    Detals, String count) {
try{
    String mysql="INSERT INTO  table_news" +
            "(Title, Image, tale, Details, Count1)" +
            "VALUES " +
            "('"+ titel +"', '"+ Image +"', '"+ table +"', '"+ Detals +"', 
  '"+ count +"')";
    sql.execSQL(mysql);
    Log.d("sql",mysql);
}catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
     }
```

and review code

```
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);
        ImageView image=new ImageView(this);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

        image.setMinimumHeight(dm.heightPixels);
        image.setMinimumWidth(dm.widthPixels);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: I'm not going to flag this, because I think you tried to ask a good question, but you need to add in what exactly isn't working, you posted a lot of code, which is fine, but if we don't know what's going wrong, we don't know where to begin looking.

Comment: Thanks for attention
The program on the android does not display the image and only displays the name and there is no problem with the software Is it possible to be the problem in the method of addition and display in the database    Unlike this all parts of the program are working